# How do I invert group permissions using bash?

Tags: bash, permissions, chmod

I'm trying to write a bash script that inverts the given file's group permissions.
For example:

if file.txt had the permissions `-rw-r--r--`, it would be inverted to `-rw--wxr--`

if file.txt had the permissions `-rw--w-r-x`, it would be inverted to `-rw-r-xr-x`

I've done something similar to this in python before, where I used the XOR bitwise operator `^` to invert the execute permissions.

I can't seem to figure out the proper way of doing this in bash
The filename will be provided as a command line argument

Comment: This isn't really an inversion. You seem to be setting `x` regardless of its previous setting, and swapping `r` for `w` and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

fname=$1                                # filename is given at the command line
perm="0$(stat -c %a "$fname")"          # permissions in oct such as 0644
iperm=$( printf "0%o" $(( perm ^ 070 )) )
                                        # invert the group permissions such as 0634
chmod "$iperm" "$fname"                 # update the file status
```